Install windows after linux from hard drive
I have an Ubuntu on my desktop, and I'd like to install win11 onto it.
Sadly, I have no media to boot, so my idea is to install it from disk, if it is possible.
So, the plan is to extract the ISO, create a bootable partition, and copy the installation files to there.
I saw some posts about how to do it directly from ISO, I just do not want to make it too complicated.
My question is, is it possible to do this? If yes, how can I say to system to use setup.exe after boot?
If I could do this, after this, how can I say to system to start with GRUB to access my Ubuntu?
Or is this a total stupid question?
Sorry for this newbee question, I just really do not want to mess up my existing ubuntu.
I could do the partitionig from a bootable linux stick.
